# Powershell Select-String if contains "xxx" but does not contain "yyy"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to select a string from a debug log which contains a specific string but does not contain a different string.

I guess this is simple but I'm totally new to powershell.

Keep getting same error.
"missing statement block after if condition"

Tried a few variations but cant get it to work.

Code i'm trying is:
`Get-Content -Path "~\filepath\debug.log"-Wait | Select-String "String 1" {if (notcontain (select-string "String 2"))}`

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help with this!

Comment: Note that your question is a bit ambiguous: Are you looking to find the word to exclude _on the same line_ as the word to match or _anywhere in the same file_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) twice as follows:

```
Get-Content -Path "~\filepath\debug.log" -Wait |
    Select-String "String 1" |
    Select-String "String 2" -NotMatch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-match` and `-notmatch` operators against the content.

Here's something that could do the trick.

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path "~\filepath\debug.log" -Raw 
$IsMatch = $Content -match 'String 1' -and $Content -notmatch 'String 2'


if ($IsMatch) {
    Write-Host 'Yay' -ForegroundColor Cyan
} else {
    Write-Host ':(' -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```